# Where to DeSerialize JSON when using JavaScript Remoting? Apex Salesforce

Tags: javascript, json, salesforce, apex-code

My scenarios is

1) Doing a JScript Remote call to an apex class

2) Calling an external webservice that returns JSON

3) Displaying the results on the VF Page

At the moment - upon the return of the JSON I am deserializing it into a custom apex class (only pulling the values that are required), and then passing it back to the client side - looping through it and populating a table.

Is this the correct implementation? or should the JSON be being passed directly to the client and parsed on the client?  - would this be better practice?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you share the example , i mean how did you made the service call to the Json webservice through Apex , Visual Force Pages amd Controllers

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct but you may find time consuming in getting the responses back from webservice.

Can you post your code?